# Boolean selection of list

Tags: haskell

Suppose we want those elements of list `x` for which the corresponding element of list `y` is strictly positive.  Any of the three solutions below work:

```
let x = [1..4]
let y = [1, -1, 2, -2]

[ snd both | both <- zip (map (> 0) y) x, fst both ]
```

or

```
map snd $ filter fst $ zip (map (>0) y) x
```

or

```
sel :: [Bool] -> [a] -> [a]
sel [] _ = []
sel (True : xs) (y : ys) = y : sel xs ys
sel (False : xs) (y : ys) = sel xs ys

sel (map (> 0) y) x
```

however, what prompted this was that in the R language this can be written compactly like this:

```
x[y > 0]
```

and given how much shorter that is I was wondering if there is a shorter/better way to do this in Haskell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not a haskell specialist, but why not use [list comprehension](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_comprehension)?

```
 [i | (i,j)  <-  zip x y, j > 0 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use a language extension, I can offer the alternative

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}

bfilter :: (b -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b] -> [a]
bfilter cond xs ys = [x | x <- xs | y <- ys, cond y]
```

Nothing in Haskell will be nearly as short as the R version, because in R, it's a language built-in, but in Haskell it isn't. Apparently whoever designed R found there to be good reasons to include such a primitive, but none of the Haskell designers found there to be convincing reasons to include such a construct in the language (and it wouldn't fit in nicely, so I fully endorse that decision - it may fit in well in R, I don't know that language).

Comment: Regarding your statement about built-ins its not just R but also in relational databases  where selection is regarded as fundamental.  For example, in SQL we have `select x from mytable where y > 0` .

Comment: Is that the same thing? As I understand it, we have two unrelated - except that they both have list (array in R?) type - entities and select entries from one based on conditions on the element of the other at the corresponding index (by the way, how does R behave if `x` and `y` have different lengths? Same as Haskell, stop at the end of the shorter, runtime error?). Is the `select x from mytable where y > 0` even possible if `y` isn't part of `mytable`?

Comment: I think we can assume whatever necessary for comparability (same lengths, same table, etc.) . The crux of the issue is more the ease of performing selection.

Comment: I don't understand. Performing the selection is as easy in Haskell as in R, just R has special syntax for it, while in Haskell you have to define your own function for that. I don't think writing your own function for that in R would be much harder than in Haskell, so I can only assume that the designer(s) of R considered it important enough to add special syntax for the operation. I'm still curious about the semantics of `x[y > 0]` in R if `x` and `y` have different lengths.

Comment: In R, `x <- 1:3; y <- c(1, -1, 2, -2); x[y > 0]` gives: `1 3` and `x[y < 0]` gives `2 NA`.  With same `y` but `x <- 1:5` we get recycling of `y < 0` or `y > 0` so that `x[y < 0]` gives `2 4` and `x[y > 0]` gives `1 3 5` .

Answer (score 1):

```
zip x y >>= \(a,b) -> filter(const(b>0)) [a]
```

Or pointlessly using Applicative...

```
import Control.Applicative

zip x y >>= filter <$> const.(>0).snd <*> (:[]).fst
```

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Fischer says, there isn't any special syntax for this.

If you're going to be doing this operation often, it's best to define your own single reusable function, instead of having to assemble the list comprehension or map/filter chain manually every time. (Your `sel` doesn't pass this test because the caller has to apply the `map` separately.)

So

```
selectWhere :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [b] -> [b]
selectWhere ys pred = map snd . filter (pred . fst) . zip ys
-- call it like this:  selectWhere y (> 0) x
```

or whichever clearer definition you prefer. The important thing is that you wrap it up inside a function.